# Virt-Manager error to create an images qcow2 on an external HDD

Tags: server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, 20.04

I've installed Virt-Manager on Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop using the same tasks used on the 19.10. 
With this last one I didn't have any issue but on 20.04 when I try to create a VM on an external HDD I receive this issue:

[image]
[image]

```
Unable to complete install: 'Cannot access storage file '/media/user/Storage' (as uid:64055, gid:108): Permission denied'
```

Seeing the details there is this

```
Unable to complete install: 'Cannot access storage file '/media/dakne/vStorage/VM/ubuntu20.04' (as uid:64055, gid:108): Permission denied'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 75, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/createvm.py", line 2089, in _do_async_install
    guest.installer_instance.start_install(guest, meter=meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/install/installer.py", line 542, in start_install
    domain = self._create_guest(
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/install/installer.py", line 491, in _create_guest
    domain = self.conn.createXML(install_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 4034, in createXML
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateXML() failed', conn=self)
libvirt.libvirtError: Cannot access storage file '/media/dakne/vStorage/VM/ubuntu20.04' (as uid:64055, gid:108): Permission denied
```

I've already done chmod 'n chown but nothing!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, never mind .... I answer myself :-)

I've run Virt-Manager as root, created a new VM selecting "Import existing disk image" and continued with the tasks. At the end it will asked me whether I want to fix the permission issues, clicking 'Yes' it'll fixes the permission issue.

Close it and run Virt-Manager with normal user too.

[image]